Как установить версию C# 10.0
Для библиотеки PostgreSQL нужна версия C# 10+, но у меня проект создается с версией 9.0
Использую Unity 2023.2.20f1,пробовал задавать версию через .csproj и csc.rsp, ничего не помогает.
В настройках юнити нельзя выбрать .NET 6.0+ и каждый проект создается с версией Framework 4.7.1 как все таки поменять версию C# на 10+

В Unity — никак

@andreymal допустим в FM25 используют Unity, но для библиотек которые способны хранить очень большое количество данных в основном используется C# 10+, каким образом они тогда хранят данные, ведь использовать их напрямую в коде это -производительность

Если я правильно понял из своего гyгла, там используется свой собственный формат, который не имеет никакого отношения к PostgreSQL или другим существующим СУБД. Что у него с производительностью — не знаю, но теоретически ничего не мешает сделать свой конкретный формат оптимизированным под свои конкретные нужды (и от версии C# это уже никак не зависит)

Зачем в Unity Postgres, если БД это сервер, а игра это клиент? Вы хотите очень странного. И дело даже не версии C#, а в версии .NET платформы.

@AYWUgst возьмите более старую версию PostgreSQL, которая подходит.
